# Template class pointers issue c++

Tags: c++

I'm wondering why I am getting these errors while using template classes. I am getting error C2440 '=' cannot convert from '`node<T> *`' to '`node<T> *`'. This seems strange since they are exactly the same type.

```
    template<class T>
    struct node
    {        
        T value;
        node<T> *next = nullptr;
        node()
        {
            this->next = nullptr;
        }

        node(T t)
        {
            this->value = t;
            this->next = nullptr;
        }

        node(T t, node<T> *nextpointer)
        {
            this->value = t;
            this->next = nextpointer;
        }

        ~node()
        {

        }
    };

    template<class T> class forwardList
    {
    private:
        node<T> *head;
    public:
        template<class T> forwardList() {}
        template<class T> forwardList(T var)
        {
            if (head == nullptr)
            {
                node<T> *firstNode = new node<T>(var);
                this->head->next = firstNode; //Here it doesn't work for me
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please post the exact text of the error message, and on which line it occurs. It also might be useful to state which version of MSVC you are using.

Comment: Why are you repeating `template<class T>` for the constructor definitions? You don't want a templated function I suppose?

Comment: It doesn't solve the error but you're trying to dereference `head` in a place where you _know_ head is `nullptr`. Even if it built, it would bomb out there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was my first post to this website and I am still pretty new to coding. I will keep your advice in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles fine for me (on MSVC) after making the following changes:

- Remove `enter code here` near the top
- Remove `template<class T>` in front of the declarations of `forwardList` constructors:

  ```
  public:
      forwardList() {}
      forwardList(T var)
      { ...
  ```